# jaeger tracing and spring cloud OpenFeign

Tags: java, spring, jaeger, openfeign

I am using a spring Cloud openFeign for making request from service#1 to service#2

When I use restTemplate I can correctly see 2 requests in jaeger tracing. But when using openFeign I see only 1 request. Is there any way of integrating jaeger and openFeign?

I found this:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-openfeign
https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign-opentracing

Answer (score 1):

`spring-cloud-openfeign` since is from the spring-cloud family should be instrumented automatically once you add `opentracing-spring-jaeger-cloud-starter` the  as stated [here](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-spring-jaeger#configuration).
But sometimes (depending on how you create your feign client bean) you need to explicitly expose the bean to the spring context, so that the autoconfiguration can instrument your Feign Client.

Something like this:

```
@Scope("prototype")
fun feignClient() : Client {
    return Client.Default(null, null)
}
```

it is kotlin but you can adapt.

Comment: Could you make it more explicit? I have this @EnableFeignClients(clients = {MyFeignClient.class}) on my Spring Boot Application, shouldn't this be enough? Is there any known issue?

Comment: The auto configuration instrument the Client(from feign) class. But it needs to be explicitly expose to the spring context otherwise it will create a new one that will not be instrumented

Comment: after adding this my tests fail:
```at my.package.feign.FeignAutoConfigurationTest.testWithAuthentication(FeignAutoConfigurationTest.java:86)
...

Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: test-service
```
anything I need to add to the tests now?

Comment: Most probably you override you host address while creating the feign client.